# Connections between graph theory and applied functional analysis for PDEs

Tags: functional-analysis, graph-theory, soft-question, research

I have a relatively strong background in the theory of numerical analysis of partial differential equations (PDEs) and functional analysis, particularly applied to the numerical analysis of PDEs using the finite element method. I'm also very interested in graph theory. I was wondering if there are any theories or research areas that unify these fields and that I could explore given my background. Are there any connections between graph theory, functional analysis, and numerical analysis of PDEs that I should be aware of?

I am aware that there is another question about this, but I am interested in it being in the context of PDEs and numerical methods. Also I am looking for open questions to initiate a research project, so I am seeking topics where the intersection is significant and there are open problems.

Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Comment: I am most certainly not the correct person to answer this question, but did you have a look into spectral graph theory, respectively the theory of quantum graphs? In both cases people try to deal with some sort of differential operator (discrete in the first case and continuous in the second) related to some underlying graph. That would somewhat fit the functional analysis and graph theory part (no idea about the type of numerics people are interested in).